# COUNT function doesn't work?

Tags: sql

I have the table FGLEDGE including (among many other) the following columns:

```
EGVONO  EGACDT      EGAIT1  EGAIT6  EGACAM
1181941 20150616    2990    1123445 3598,8
1181942 20150616    2990    1118741 136249,65
1181943 20150616    2990    1121430 20874,9
1181944 20150616    2990    1122177 21569,5
1181945 20150616    2990    6215746 340
1181946 20150630    2990    1121844 26395,8
1181946 20150630    2990    1123293 52453,15
1181946 20150630    2990    6213402 514,12
1181946 20150630    2990    6213404 514,12
1181947 20150616    2990    1120779 89568
1181948 20150616    2990    1122610 11972,73
```

I want a query that will return all rows that for a SPECIFIC voucher number (EGVONO) has several different numbers in column EGAIT6.

My query is:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT FGLEDG.EGAIT6),
FGLEDG.EGVONO, 
FGLEDG.EGACDT, 
FGLEDG.EGAIT1, 
FGLEDG.EGAIT6, 
FGLEDG.EGACAM

FROM SEUHABOB.MVXADTA001.FGLEDG FGLEDG

WHERE (FGLEDG.EGCONO=001) 
AND (FGLEDG.EGDIVI='D16') 
AND (FGLEDG.EGTRCD=41) 
AND (FGLEDG.EGVONO=1181946) 
AND (FGLEDG.EGAIT1='2990')
AND COUNT (DISTINCT FGLEDG.EGAIT6)>1
```

And the expected result should be

```
EGVONO  EGACDT  EGAIT1  EGAIT6  EGAIT7  EGACAM       COUNT
1181946 20150630    2990    1121844 PP20225 26395,8  4
1181946 20150630    2990    1123293 PP20225 52453,15 4
1181946 20150630    2990    6213402 PP20225 514,12   4
1181946 20150630    2990    6213404 PP20225 514,12   4
```

I get the error message: "Use of function COUNT not valid".

Why doesn't the Count function work? Am I writing it wrong?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: You can make your question easier to answer by following this recommendations: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Limited information but I will give it a try. COUNT probably expects a GROUP BY as well (on all the columns returned that are not in the count statement.)

Comment: ODBC (if that is a database?).

I'm using Excel to whrite the SQL-code.

I've tried to GROUP BY but get the same error message: "Use of function COUNT not valid".

Comment: ODBC is not a DBMS, what's the name of the ODBC driver?

Comment: Could it be iSeries Access ODBC Driver?

Comment: See my answer, hopefully Access supports it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count and the details you need to find the matching `EGVONO` first and then join back:

```
SELECT 
FGLEDG.EGVONO, 
FGLEDG.EGACDT, 
FGLEDG.EGAIT1, 
FGLEDG.EGAIT6, 
FGLEDG.EGACAM,
dt.CNT

FROM SEUHABOB.MVXADTA001.FGLEDG FGLEDG
JOIN
 (
   SELECT 
      FGLEDG.EGVONO,
      COUNT(DISTINCT FGLEDG.EGAIT6) AS CNT
   FROM SEUHABOB.MVXADTA001.FGLEDG FGLEDG
   WHERE (FGLEDG.EGCONO=001) 
   AND (FGLEDG.EGDIVI='D16') 
   AND (FGLEDG.EGTRCD=41) 
   AND (FGLEDG.EGVONO=1181946) 
   AND (FGLEDG.EGAIT1='2990')
   GROUP BY FGLEDG.EGVONO
   HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT FGLEDG.EGAIT6)>1
 ) AS dt
ON FGLEDG.EGVONO = dt.EGVONO
WHERE (FGLEDG.EGCONO=001) 
AND (FGLEDG.EGDIVI='D16') 
AND (FGLEDG.EGTRCD=41) 
AND (FGLEDG.EGVONO=1181946) 
AND (FGLEDG.EGAIT1='2990')
```

Hopefully Access supports that...

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to use comment to say thanks so I'll just go YYYYYYYYYYYEEEEEEEEYYYYYYYYYYYY! It works! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a GROUP BY and your filter of COUNT(..) > 1 needs to be in a HAVING clause rather than WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT FGLEDG.EGAIT6),
    FGLEDG.EGVONO, 
    FGLEDG.EGACDT, 
    FGLEDG.EGAIT1, 
    FGLEDG.EGAIT6, 
    FGLEDG.EGACAM

FROM SEUHABOB.MVXADTA001.FGLEDG FGLEDG

WHERE (FGLEDG.EGCONO=001) 
    AND (FGLEDG.EGDIVI='D16') 
    AND (FGLEDG.EGTRCD=41) 
    AND (FGLEDG.EGVONO=1181946) 
    AND (FGLEDG.EGAIT1='2990')
GROUP BY 
    FGLEDG.EGVONO, 
    FGLEDG.EGACDT, 
    FGLEDG.EGAIT1, 
    FGLEDG.EGAIT6, 
    FGLEDG.EGACAM
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT FGLEDG.EGAIT6)>1
```

Try this.

Comment: Now the SQL itself works, but it returns nothing. :(